# Understanding a subset of linear transformations with 2 DOF produced by 3 shear transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm interested in a subset of linear transformations of the plane that has only two degrees of freedom. They must have determinant equal to 1, thus a subset of the special linear group. The other constraint is that, apart from a pure scaling, it does not contain the pure squeeze either. This subset contains pure rotations and shearing.

I'm trying to understand what subsets like this can be defined, and how they can be complemented to form the complete set of linear transformations. While I don't think such a set can form a closed group like rotations, I would like to understand what other interesting properties it may have. Could it be related to a matrix decomposition? I'm especially interested in finding out ways to parameterize these transformations.

Some alternatives I have explored were a shear followed by a rotation, or vice-versa. I am not sure these definitions create the same subsets, or which is the most complete. So that's the first question.

The most interesting definition I have found is a shear on the x dimension followed by a shear on y and then on x again repeating the first operation:

$$
A(\alpha,\beta) = \left[\matrix{ 1 & \alpha \cr 0 & 1}\right]
\left[\matrix{ 1 & 0 \cr \beta & 1}\right]
\left[\matrix{ 1 & \alpha \cr 0 & 1}\right]
$$

This is an orientation and area-preserving transformation, that becomes a pure rotation if $\beta=\sin(\theta)$ and $\alpha=-\tan(\theta/2)$. It can also produce pure shearing at either the x or y directions, although I'm not even sure about other axes. It has the nice property that the inverse transformation is obtained by just changing the sign of the parameters, although like I said it does not seem to form a group.

The question is then: what exactly is this subset of transformations represented by the formula above? Can it be made more complete while still having only two degrees of freedom? And how it relates to the complete set of linear transformations?

A little bit more context: I'm basically looking for the largest set of transformations with 2DOF that can be parameterized in such a way that changing one parameter necessarily affects the angles of lines anywhere on the plane (except for lines exactly at the shearing axis). Therefore rotations and shearing, excluding scaling and pure squeezing. What is this set of transformations?

Comment: This seems to be the set of unitary Toeplitz matrices.